# Remove specific subsection of a specific section in a YAML file

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm trying to remove some subsections of a specific 'section' in a YAML file. Regarding the code below, only for John array `- name: john`, I only want to remove the whole info subsection if his nationality equals/contains `english`.

So the file below **data.yml**

```
 persons:
 - name: alice
 - name: jane
 - name: john
   info:
      nationality: english
- name: michael
    info:
      nationality: french
- name: steve
    info:
      age: '19'

animals:
  - name: cat
```

Becomes this

```
 persons:
 - name: alice
 - name: jane
 - name: john
 - name: michael
    info:
      nationality: french
 - name: steve
    info:
      age: '19'

animals:
  - name: cat
```

I've only came up with the code below, but this code deletes john and his subsections completely.

```
yq 'del(.persons[] | select(.info.[] | select(.=="*english*")))' data.yml

 - name: john
   info:
      nationality: english
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this specific operation? I cannot seem to do the precise operation, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Keep `.info` outside the `select` statement, as it is what you want to `del`ete:

```sh
yq 'del(.persons[].info | select(.nationality == "english"))' data.yml
```

```yaml
persons:
  - name: alice
  - name: jane
  - name: john
  - name: michael
    info:
      nationality: french
  - name: steve
    info:
      age: '19'
animals:
  - name: cat
```

For a [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) version prior to 4.18.1, add the `eval` command; for [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) add the `-y` option.

---

To test for containment instead of for equality, you can use the `contains` function:

```sh
yq 'del(.persons[].info | select(.nationality | contains("english")))' data.yml
```

Again, add the `eval` command when using mikefarah/yq prior to version 4.18.1. For the kislyuk/yq solution, besides the `-y` option you also need to suppress errors from `contains` using `?`, as the `jq` interpreter throws an error if `contains` is fed with `null`, which is the case if `.nationality` does not exist:

```
yq -y 'del(.persons[].info | select(.nationality | contains("english")?))' data.yml
```